# How to increase row length in db2 column organized table

Tags: db2, db2-luw

I want to run the following command to create a column organized table:

```
CREATE TABLE T0 (ABC VARCHAR(8000)) IN abc_tablespace organize by column
```

I get the following error:

```
SQL0670N  The statement failed because the row or column size of the resulting
            table would have exceeded the row or column size limit: "3920". Table space
            name: "ABC_TABLESPACE". Resulting row or column size: "8000".  SQLSTATE=54010
```

I have the extended_row_sz enabled. I checked and verified this. Not sure if this is only valid for row org tables or not. I do not want to enable `DB2_WORKLOAD=ANALYTICS`. I have just set `INTRA_PARALLEL YES`. Anyone know how I can create this column in an column organized table?

Comment: What is the tablespace page size? You only have a single column and that needs to fit in. What Db2 version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to create your table in a tablespace with a larger page size. Typically Column Organized tables are created in a 32K page-size tablespace, although this is not mandatory.
Setting DB2_WORKLOAD=ANALYTICS before creating a database https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.dbobj.doc/doc/t0061527.html  sets the default page size to 32K. As you don't want to enable this parameter, you will need to create a 32K (or 16K or 8K) tablespace (and bufferpool) and create your table in it.

Answer (score 0):

Extended row size support does not apply to column-organized tables.

This is stated here: [CREATE TABLE](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000927.html), if you search by the phrase above.